# How do you add data to firebase doc using redux thunk getFireBase and getFirestore from react-redux-firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux, react-redux-firebase

## Problem

- I'm having trouble adding data to the firebase database using react-redux-thunk
- I've checked the documentation and watched multiple youtube videos but keeping running into error after error
- I want to add data to a firebase doc using the `getFirestore` and `getFirebase` middleware from the "redux-firestore" and "react-redux-firebase" library respectively

## Code

- Here is the action function
- All the code seems to be working but I can't figure out how to add `validatonResults` to `users/uid` (see comment in code below)
- Tried the following code (and a lot of other stuff) but it didn't work `firebase.push('users', { data: validatonResults })`

```
import inputValidationAPI from "../../apis/inputValidationAPI"

export const validateTestCase = payload => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
        const fireStore = getFirestore()
        const firebase = getFirebase()
        const uid = getState().firebase.auth.uid

        inputValidationAPI
            .post("/submitTerm", {
                term: payload
            })
            .then(response => {
                return response.data.data
            })
            .then(validatonResults => {
                /* 
                validationResults = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
                I want to take validationResults and add them into firebase collection something like:
                
                firebase.push('todos/${uid}', { some: 'data' }) 
                */

                return validatonResults
            })
            .then(validatonResults => {
                dispatch({
                    type: "VALIDATE_TESTCASE_SUCCESS",
                    payload: validatonResults
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
}
```

Comment: While adding data to the firebase database, what is the trouble that you are facing? Could you show your error here?

Comment: figured it out, closing this issue

Comment: @OG_On_The_Beat what you have figured out?. can you post that as answer. It will help community when some one came across same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following syntax solved this:

```
fireStore.update(
          { collection: "users", doc: uid },
          { dataToSave: someJSONObject },
     }
)
```